# MVC and HTML5 Validation: conflict with the decimal format

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html, data-annotations

I've got an input element:

**View**

```
<input 
type="number" 
min="0" 
max="100" 
step="1" 
value="@Model.Percentage" 
name="Percentage" />
```

**Model**

```
[Required][Range(0.2,10000)][DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Percentage { get; set; }
```

In this way the input type stays empty in the browser.

I can force it by replacing the comma with a dot in the percentage ToString.

But then the DataAnnotations don't work any more.

Also have a look to HTML5 rendered input and the default MVC rendered input:

```
<input 
class="text-box single-line 
input-validation-error" 
data-val="true" 
data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number." 
data-val-range="The field Percentage must be between 0 and 100." 
data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0" 
data-val-required="The field Percentage is mandatory" 
id="Percentage" name="Percentage" type="text" value="0,0" 
aria-required="true" 
aria-invalid="true" 
aria-describedby="Percentage-error Percentage-error Percentage-error Percentage-error">

<input type="number" 
min="0" 
max="100" 
step="1" 
value="1" 
name="Percentage" 
aria-invalid="false" 
aria-describedby="Percentage-error Percentage-error" 
class="valid">
```

Comment: Please show your code, can't help you without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVC html helpers instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Percentage)
```

You can add attributes to the MVC-generated markup like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Percentage, new { @type = "number", @step="1", @min = "0", @max = "100" })
```

Comment: But in this way I will loose the nice stuffs added by HTML5? I mean the step incrementing and so on?

Comment: I've added the diffference between HTML5 and MVC controls

Comment: I've used @Html.TextBoxFor, but now I get a conflict in the validation.. The Javascript validator thinks that this symbol is wrong "," but MVC is using that symbol...